# I can not figure out how to have the bot DM a user that I tag

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to send a user a reminder in DM that their subscription is due for renewal in 3 days.
At the moment it sends in the channel but not everyone sees it so I want it to DM them. I want the command to be like this

```
!subreminder 10 @user
```

here is my current code that sends to the channel but does not DM

```
@client.command()
async def subreminder(ctx, arg1):
    amt = arg1
    # Discord Embed Setup   
    embed = Embed(
        description="This is a reminder that your subscription payment of **$"+amt+"** is due in 3 days. If you wish to cancel please let one of the owners know.",
        color=DiscordEmbedColor,
        timestamp='now'  # sets the timestamp to current time
        )

    embed.set_title(title="**Subscription Reminder**", url=Link)


    embed.set_footer(text=DiscordFooterText, icon_url=DiscordFooterIcon)


    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> here is my current code that sends to the channel but does not DM

Well yes, because you're using `ctx.send()`. In order to DM a user, you can just use `user.send()`. Getting the `discord.User` instance can be achieved with a `converter`.

```
async def subreminder(ctx, amt, user: discord.User):
    # code that creates the embed
    await user.send(embed=embed)
```